# Is it possible to create a button that only affects the div it is in, while buttons in other divs use the same script code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have Jquery code for unchecking form input checkboxes. I'm trying to figure out how to make it only affect the list item its contained in, but I can't find anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".check").click(function() {
    $(".myCheck").prop("checked", true);
  });
  $(".uncheck").click(function() {
    $(".myCheck").prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```

```css
.appslist {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0%;
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
}

.appslist li {
  display: block;
  width: 18.33%;
  padding-left: 5.356%;
  padding-right: 5.356%;
  margin: 0%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.ecard {
  height: 100%;
}

.log {
  height: 85%;
}

.logheader {
  height: 15%;
}

.resetbutton {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

.logheader {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

.logheader h1 {
  margin: 0%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="appslist">
  <li>
    <div class="ecard">
      <div class="logheader">
        <h1>Div1</h1>
        <button type="button" class="uncheck resetbutton"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="log">
        <form>
          <div class="setinput">
            <h6>
            <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck">20</input> Set 1 </h6>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="ecard">
      <div class="logheader">
        <h1>Div2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="log">
        <form>
          <div class="setinput">
            <h6><input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"> 20</input> Set 1 </h6>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: `.closest('div')` and then check the element for whatever conditions you are looking for.  Or use [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: *list item its contained in* would be `$(this).closest("li")`

Answer (score 0):

find [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) parent matching selector

```
    $(this).closest('div.ecard').find(".myCheck").prop("checked", true);
```

`$(this).closest('li')` would also work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div.ecard').find(".myCheck").prop("checked", true);
    });
    $(".uncheck").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div.ecard').find(".myCheck").prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

```css
.appslist{ list-style: none; padding: 0%; display: block; height: 90%; }
.appslist li{ display: block; width: 18.33%; padding-left: 5.356%; padding-right: 5.356%; margin: 0%; float: left; max-height: 100%;}
.ecard{height: 100%;}
.log{ height: 85%;}
.logheader{ height: 15%;}
.resetbutton{float: left; height: 100%; width: 20%;}
  .logheader{text-align: center;  border-bottom: 2px solid black; border: 5px solid black; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-content: center;}
  .logheader h1{margin: 0%; font-size: 1.5vw;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="appslist">
          <li><div class="ecard">
            <div class="logheader">
              <h1>Div1</h1>
              <button type="button" class="uncheck resetbutton"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="log">
              <form>
                <div class="setinput"><h6><input type="checkbox" class="myCheck">20</input> Set 1 </h6> </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div></li>
          <li><div class="ecard">
            <div class="logheader">
              <h1>Div2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="log">
              <form>
                <div class="setinput"><h6><input type="checkbox" class="myCheck"> 20</input> Set 1 </h6> </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div></li>
```